# How to set column width of Jtable equal to a checkbox

Tags: java, swing

Below is the picture.
[image]

I am using following code but it's not setting width to size of checkbox

```
TableColumn column = null;
        column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        column.setPreferredWidth(1);
```

I want to remove spaces around checkbox

Comment: are you using the default boolean editor?

Comment: only way to go around it is to probably create your own renderer object for the column

Comment: are you using TableViewer ?

Comment: @OliverWatkins Sorry what do you mean? I am adding row like this: `dtm.addRow(new Object[] { Boolean.FALSE ,Pages,Key,Title,Author,TimeStamp});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TableColumn has 3 widths, minimum, preferred and maximum.

Setting the width to 1 makes no sense since the checkbox won't paint in 1 pixel, so I would guess the minimum value is being used. Also, depending on the auto resize property the value could be overridden to make sure the column widths will fill the table view.

Try setting the minimum and preferred sizes to the same (reasonable) value.

A better approach is to not guess at the width since it could change for different LAF's. Instead you can use the renderer to determine the appropriate width for the column. See [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) for basic example code you can use and a more complex class that provides a complete solution.

Comment: seems some 3rd party class?

Comment: Yes, this feature is not support in the JDK.